# Atiyah-Macdonald proposition 10.15 $\hat{A}\mathfrak{a}$

Tags: commutative-algebra

[image: prop 10.15]

I don't understand the symbol $\widehat A \mathfrak{a}$.
I saw the following post, but I still have the question.

[Atiyah-Macdonald, Chapter 10, Proposition 10.15 clarifications](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/760052/1186046)
There is following answer.

> Suppose $R\rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism and $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $R$. Do you know what $\mathfrak{a}S$ means? It means the ideal in $S$ generated by the image of $\mathfrak{a}$ under the homomorphism. $\hat{A}\mathfrak{a}$ means the same thing here. And yes, $\hat{\mathfrak{a}}$ is an ideal of $\hat{A}$.

From the answer of the post, I think $\widehat{A}\mathfrak{a}$ is the following meaning.

> Let $f_A:A\to \widehat{A}$  be natural homomorphism. Then $\widehat{A}\mathfrak{a}=\widehat{A}f_A(\mathfrak{a})$

But,$f_A$ is a ring homomorphism that is not written on the proof but my idea.

Followings is my idea.

> Let $f_\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{a}\to \widehat{\mathfrak{a}}$ be natural homomorphism. Then I think $\phi:\hat{A}\otimes \mathfrak{a}\to \hat{\mathfrak{a}}$  is  $\sum a_i\otimes x_i\mapsto \sum a_if_\mathfrak{a}(x_i)$.
> Therefore the image of $\phi$ is $\widehat{A}f_\mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a})$.

But it is not natural to write $\widehat{A}f_\mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a})$ as $\widehat{A}\mathfrak{a}$.

So I'm wondering if the author meant something else by this symbol $\widehat{A}\mathfrak{a}$.

Please tell me the correct meaning.